# RegEx which accepts only two decimal places

Tags: regex, xml

Hi I am working on RegEx. Correct response should NOT allow for number to the tenths only, as in RESPONSE = "925.0", nor should it allow for trailing zeros after the hundredths place as in RESPONSE = "925.000". Only correct responses: 925, 0925, 0925., 925., 925.00, 00925

I worked on it and finally came up with this

```
"^-?(0)*(\d*(\.(00))?\d+.|(\d){1,3}(,(\d){3})*(\.(00))?)$"
```

It works for three digit numbers but if i want it for 38400.00 it doesn't allow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite certain whether the decimal places can be any digit or if they have to be zero. If the former, then this should do the trick:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.(\d{2})?)?$
```

If the latter, then this:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.(00)?)?$
```

The entire match starting with the decimal point is optional, and the two decimal places in that match are optional as well.

**UPDATE** I just realized that it appears you need to accept commas in the response as well - I assume for thousands, millions, etc.

**UPDATE #2 per OP's comment**

```
^-?(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.(00)?)?$
```

**UPDATE #3** Added [link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nB2zC5/1) for explanation of this regular expression.

Comment: But look at the test value that isn't working -- he's trying to input `38400.00`, which has no commas, and that might well be what's tripping him up.

Comment: Note that the comma is optional; that is why it has a `?` following it. I've tested `38400.00` with my regex and it works.

Comment: I want commas also in the response it should take everything like 038,400.00 or 0,003,840.00 but it should only take two zeros after decimal point. i.e is it should not take 38400.0 or 38400.000

Comment: Would you be so kind as to accept the answer and/or upvote? Thanks!

Comment: I got one more problem it is taking 0,38400.00. It should take only if the commas are placed in right places. for example it should take 0,038,400.00 but not 0,038400.00 because one comma is missing. Can you help @DavidFaber

Comment: Please see my update above. Made the comma non-optional, and added an option for *only* digits to be allowed before the decimal point: `^-?(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.(00)?)?$`

Comment: Ah, I missed that `?`. My bad. Could you post a quick explanation of how it works, though? I'm confused.

Comment: @newbiedoodle, if you follow a character with a question mark `?`, it's the same as using `{0,1}` meaning it's optional to match that character.

Comment: @David I know. I meant of the entire regex, not just the `?`. I'd like to understand how it works.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, perhaps this would help? Probably a better explanation than the one I would give https://regex101.com/r/nB2zC5/1

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.(?:00)?)?$
```

Comment: Just checked; it will. The last bit shouldn't have the inner `?` (i.e. it should be `(\.00)?`

Comment: The other thing is that the TWO decimal places are themselves optional. That is, there can be a trailing `.`. So I think you want to replace `00` with `(00)?`

Comment: @VikasBuddharaju: Yes, it does. Try it.

Comment: Nice with the non-capturing groups ... hopefully the OP is just validating and doesn't need the data :)

Comment: I got one more problem it is taking 0,38400.00. It should take only if the commas are placed in right places. for example it should take 0,038,400.00 but not 0,038400.00 because one comma is missing. Can you help @JESUISCHARLIE

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're trying to match it in chunks of three, with commas separating, but `38400.00` doesn't have commas.

Try this:

```
^-?\d+(\.?(\d{2})?)$
```

The `-` indicates the character, -. With the `?` after, it says that it may or may not apply. This allows negative numbers, so if you only want positive numbers matched, delete the first two characters.

`\d` represents every digit. The `+` after says that there can be as many as you want, as long as there's at least one.

Then there's a `\.`, which is just a dot in the number. The `?` does the same as before.. Since you seem to allow trailing periods, I assumed you wanted it to be considered separately from the following digits.

The `()` encloses the next group, which is the period (`\.`) followed by two characters that match `\d` -- two digits -- and which may be repeated 0 or 1 times, as dictated by the `?`. This allows people to either have no digits after the period or two, but nothing else.

The `^` at the beginning specifies it has to be at the beginning of the line, and the `$` at the end specifies it has to end at the end of the line. Remember to enable the multiline (`m`) flag so it works properly.

Disclaimer: I've not done much regex work before, so I could well be totally off. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this without the ?'s

```
^[0-9,]+(\.){0,1}(\d{2}){0,1}$

improved: ^\d+[0-9,]*(\.){0,1}(\d{2}){0,1}$
```

**Edit:**
Broken down a bit as requested

Old one:

```
[0-9,]+
```

1 or more digits/commas (would have accepted ',' as true) so improved version:

```
\d+
```

for starts with 1 or more digits

```
[0-9,]*
```

0 or more digits/commas

followed by

```
(\.){0,1}
```

0 or 1 decimal

Followed by

```
(\d{2}){0,1}
```

0 or 1 of (exactly 2 digits)

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining your regex.